# EIP 1559 signed transaction stuck, now can't do anything on metamask either

Tags: transactions, evm, pending-transactions, eip-1559

```
contract_txn = weth_contract.functions.redeem(address, True).buildTransaction({
                                'type': '0x2',
                                'chainId': 43114,                            
                                'gas': 8000000,
                                'maxFeePerGas': 2 * block['baseFeePerGas'],  # required for dynamic fee transactions
                                'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 0,  # required for dynamic fee transactions
                                'nonce': nonce,
    })


signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(contract_txn, privatekey)
tx_hash =w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    })
```

Above is the transaction sign formatting I have been using. I have been doing this on the Avalanche network and it used to work instantly.

But when I tried it again recently, it would take anywhere from 10 mins to forever to get broadcast on the chain.

If I keep attempting to broadcast the same transaction with the same nonce, I eventually end up with the following error.

```
    tx_hash =w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
  File "/home/blackwidow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 698, in send_raw_transaction
    return self._send_raw_transaction(transaction)
  File "/home/blackwidow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "/home/blackwidow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 187, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "/home/blackwidow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 168, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'already known'}
```

I have forked the network and tried it locally using the same format. The tx was broadcast and the change was made to my wallet balance instantly when it was local.

Comment: Resend the transaction with increased gasPrice to replace the current one.

Comment: @rlib would that work for a PoS chain like Avalanche?